# Count unique values in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'd like to count unique values in a html table.(RGB color)

I'm using a third-party website, which using PHP to write values in the table. I don't have access to the PHP script.

The PHP writes here "{colorcode}" a rgb-to-hex which I defined. I've 5 hex values:
fire: #FF8C00
medical help: #FD0202
hazardous materials: #19070B
other: #4876FF
technical assistance: #0000FF

My goal is, that I can count each color individually and write it in an other table.
Here's my website which shows the table: https://www.feuerwehr-forstern.de/einsaetze/

Table which I want to count.

```html
<table>
<tr style="font-size:16px; background-color:#670200; color:#FFFFFF;">
<th><b>Nr.</b></th>
<th><b>Missionstart</b></th>
<th><b>Title</b></th>
<th><b>Kind of mission</b></th>
<th><b>Place</b></th>
<th></th>
</tr>{liststart}
<tr>
<td style="color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor={colorcode}><b>{missionnr}</b></td>
<td>{startdate} {starttime}</td>
<td>{missiontitle}</td>
<td>{kind of mission}</td>
<td>{missionplace}</td>
<td><u>{linkreport}</u></td>
</tr>{listend}
</table>
```

Other table, where I want to write the result of counting after " : ".

```html
<table>
<tr style="font-size:16px; color:#FFFFFF;">
<th style="background-color:#FF8C00;"><b>fire:</b></th>
<th style="background-color:#FD0202;"><b>medical help:</b></th>
<th style="background-color:#19070B;"><b>hazardous materials:</b></th>
<th style="background-color:#4876FF;"><b>other:</b></th>
<th style="background-color:#0000FF;"><b>technical assistance:</b></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. How do the colours you've listed, or `{colorcode}`, have any bearing on the first HTML sample? Also you've shown no effort to solve this yourself. Remember that we're here to help you debug code *you've written*, not to write code for you

Comment: Heres my website where you can see the table: https://www.feuerwehr-forstern.de/einsaetze/. I'd tried it with JS and jQuery. From pages like this: http://www.aspdotnetcode.com/article/get-count-number-of-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript-and-jquery or this https://forums.asp.net/t/2138215.aspx?How+to+get+the+Count+of+Unique+values+from+html+table+column but I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this : `var blue_count = $('[bgcolor=#0000FF]').length` to get the count of the `td` elements that have the `bgcolor` attribute with the value of `#0000FF` . then you can append the count value where ever you want.

but this is just the idea for you to solve it... not the best way...

good luck

Comment: I've a problem. The code works only for one color. I can't count the other colors. I've changed the variable names, the hex code etc. but nothing worked.

Comment: Code is underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new Code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var orange_count = $('[bgcolor=#ff8c00]').size()
$(".important1").text("Brand: " + orange_count);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var red_count = $('[bgcolor=#fd0202]').size()
$(".important2").text("First Responder: " + red_count);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var black_count = $('[bgcolor=#19070b]').size()
$(".important3").text("Gefahrstoffe: " + black_count);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var royalblue_count = $('[bgcolor=#4876ff]').size()
$(".important4").text("Sonstige: " + royalblue_count);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var blue_count = $('[bgcolor=#0000FF]').size()
$(".important5").text("Technische Hilfeleistung: " + blue_count);
});
</script>
<table>
<tr style="font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
<th style="background-color: #ff8c00;"><b class="important1">Brand</b></th>
<th style="background-color: #fd0202;"><b class="important2">First Responder</b></th>
<th style="background-color: #19070b;"><b class="important3">Gefahrstoffe</b></th>
<th style="background-color: #4876ff;"><b class="important4">Sonstige</b></th>
<th style="background-color: #0000ff;"><b class="important5">Technische Hilfeleistung</b></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your code and the link you provided in your question at top,
and in the link the color codes were all Uppercase like this : `bgcolor="#4876FF"` 
so you can't get them with lowercase selectors like this:  `$('[bgcolor=#4876ff]').size()`
you should fix that at first. and then, in every page you only need to check for the document.ready event once. so one of these will do the work :

```
$(function() {

});
```

just write your code in one of these blocks. 
wish you luck...